# RDP server traffic overloaded

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

I've got a dedicated server and I know the IP, username, and password. I ran a program on it and the program used almost all the server's bandwidth so I can't log on to close it. When I want to log in to the RDP server, I wait about 30 seconds then the server lets me enter a password, then connection fails because of the low bandwidth. What can I do?

Comment: Reboot it through the web console?

Comment: is there a command to reboot a dedicated server?

Comment: Or just put in a support ticket with the provider asking them to reboot it manually.

Comment: OK. Thank you all. So I'll tell them and wait.